# ListAdapter Network calls download files from server & show the progress using WorkManager

Tags: android, listadapter, android-livedata, android-workmanager, android-listadapter

I am interested to know the design of downloading file using retrofit & displaying progress on Item adapter.

I am using work manager to do my work and downloading the files using retrofit but at present I didn't find any way to display progress on items.

Please find my code as below.

Adapter code

```
class PamphletListAdapter(
        appExecutors: AppExecutors,
        private val callback: ClickCallback)
    : DataBoundListAdapter<PamphletModel, PamphletCardViewBinding>(appExecutors,
        PamphletListItemDiff()) {

    override fun createBinding(parent: ViewGroup): PamphletCardViewBinding {
        return PamphletCardViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    }

    override fun bind(binding: PamphletCardViewBinding, item: PamphletModel, position: Int, isLast: Boolean) {
        binding.pamphletModel = item
        binding.pamphletItemView.setOnClickListener {
            binding.pamphletModel?.let { data ->
                callback.onClick(data, position)
            }
        }
    }

    interface ClickCallback {
        fun onClick(data: PamphletModel, position: Int)
    }
}
```

OnClick handler on Fragment.

```
private fun addToDownload(position: Int, data: PamphletModel) {
    history.push(position)
    val workData: Data = Data.Builder()
            .putString(Constants.WORK_MANAGER_DATA, PamphletModel.getStringFromPamphlets(data))
            .putInt(Constants.WORK_MANAGER_POSITION, position)
            .build()

    val fileManager = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<FileDownLoadManagerWorker>()
            .setInputData(workData).build()

    WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(fileManager.id).observe(this@PamphletListFragment, Observer {
        handlePDFDownloadResponse(fileManager, it)
    })

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(fileManager)
}
```

Work Manager code.

```
override fun doWork(): Result {
    val pamphletModel = PamphletModel.getPamphletsFromString(inputData.getString(Constants.WORK_MANAGER_DATA))


    if (PatwFileUtils.checkCacheFilesExist(pamphletModel.pdfPath, pamphletModel.thumbnailPath)) {
        return Result.success()
    }

    val rootDirectory = PatwFileUtils.getPamphletDirectory(context)

    //download pdf
    pamphletModel.pdfPath = DownloadManager.downloadFile(pamphletModel.downloadUrl, PatwFileUtils.getPamphletPDFFilePath(rootDirectory, pamphletModel.pamphletId))?.path

    //Download image -> save on thumbnail Path
    pamphletModel.thumbnailPath = getPamphletThumbnailImage(context, pamphletModel)

    pamphletModel.isDownloaded = Constants.PDF_STATUS_DOWNLOADED

    pamphletModel.createAt = Date()

    //Insert data to database
    pamphletDao.insert(pamphletModel)

    val outputData = createOutputData(pamphletModel, inputData.getInt(Constants.WORK_MANAGER_POSITION, 0))
    Timber.i("Work successfully completed...$pamphletModel")
    return Result.success(outputData)
}
```

Observer code to work manager completion.

```
private fun handlePDFDownloadResponse(fileManager: OneTimeWorkRequest, workInfo: WorkInfo) {
    Timber.i("Work id = ${fileManager.id}  State =  ${workInfo.state} ")
    if (workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED) {
        val result = workInfo.outputData

        val resultPosition: Int = result.getInt(Constants.WORK_MANAGER_POSITION, 0)
        val resultData = PamphletModel.getPamphletsFromString(result.getString(Constants.WORK_MANAGER_DATA))
        resultData.isDownloaded = Constants.PDF_STATUS_DOWNLOADED
        pamphletListAdapter.notifyItemChanged(resultPosition)

        if (!history.empty() && history.peek() == resultPosition) {
            history.clear()
            UtilIntent.launchPamphletFragment(context!!, configuration, resultData)
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to show the progress on item, Do let me know if any other class code required.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update some other data source with your progress.  WorkManager does not provide this.  For example, you can update the progress in some side database using Room, and observe the value using a LiveData.

Comment: I tried this but I can only update progress for particular item, Hence i decided to use "Coroutine" inplace of "Work Manager" to fixed problem